# F# - How to make a copy of elements in a list?

Tags: list, f#

I wish to write something that can make copies of all the elements in a list. So if I wanted 2 of list

```
[1; 2; 3; 4]
```

it would become

```
[1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 4]
```

So I was planning on writing a function recursively with

```
let rec dupeElem row count =
  match row with
  | [] -> []
  | hd::tl -> (makeCopy hd count) @ dupeElem tl count
```

where count is the number of copies I want. The function will take each head element in the list and send it to the copy function to make copies to insert back into the list. Then makeCopy would look like:

```
let makeCopy elem Count =
  match Count with 
  | 0 -> []
  | 1 -> elem
  | 2 -> elem :: elem
  |....
```

But I get errors for when it returns back to dupeElem. I understand doing hard cases would not be the wisest idea but it was to test whether it can work or not. How would I fix/improve what I have to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`makeCopy` returns a list for the `0` case, but for the `1` case you are returning a single element. Changing the case for `1` to the following should fix a compile time error:

```
| 1 -> [elem]
```

For case `2`, your use of `::` is invalid because the right hand side is not a list, but it is a single element. Consider replacing it with either of the following:

```
| 2 -> elem :: [elem]
```

Or...

```
| 2 -> [ elem; elem ]
```

Comment: It is still giving me type errors saying it is `expecting a list list` but getting a `int list`

Answer (score 8):

Just for the sake of non-recursive solutions:

```
let xs = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
xs |> List.collect (fun x -> List.replicate 3 x)
//val it : int list = [1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 3; 3; 3; 4; 4; 4; 5; 5; 5]
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not know of this method.

Answer (score 2):

A mutually recursive way:

```
let rec dupl n = function
    | []   -> []
    | h::t -> cons h (dupl n t) n
and cons h t = function
    | 0 -> t
    | n -> cons h (h::t) (n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by `s952163` is clean and straightforward. For more generality, if you don't just want to replicate, you could define functions f, g, and h, and do the following:

```
let xs = [1; 2; 3; 4]
let f = id // No need for type annotation, given the definitions of g and h
let g x = x * x
let h x = x * x * x
(List.zip3 xs xs xs) |> List.map (fun (a, b, c) -> [f a; g b; h c]) |> List.concat
```

For your specific case in which you just want to replicate you could do

```
let f = id<int> // The type annotation is necessary
```

and similarly for g and h or just use f for all three cases. Of course in this case the solution proposed by `s952163` is much preferred.